# Method for obtaining all combinations of consonants and vowels, the method consuming enough memory

Tags: java, algorithm, memory, logic, combinations

The problem I have to solve is to create all possible words using consonants and vowels, where I have two array list:

The first `A = {a, e, i, o, u}`, composed only by vowels.
The second `B = {b, c, d, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, n, p, q, r, t, v, x, y, w, z}`, behave by consonants.

With these two I need to generate all possible combinations of words using a consonant and a vowel, for example:

```
01 - babebi, 02 - babebu ...
```

And using a third array, I need to add a numeric value to the end of each word with the following array list:
`C = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`, where it will be possible to use only two algorithms, for example:

`01 - babebi01, 02 - babebi02, 03 - babebi03 ...` without repeating numbers and for all words.

For this I have the following code:

With this method I generate all words using the consonants and vowels:

Where I generate all pairs, consonant and vowel.

```
private void getRandomPairs(Values obj) {

        for (String vowel: obj.getVowels()) {
            for (String consonat: obj.getConsonants()) {
                pairsLetters.add(consonat + vowel);
            }
        }
}
```

Then with all the pairs saved in a list, I generate all the words.

```
private List<String> generateWord() {

        for (int i = 0; i < pairsLetters.size(); ++i){

            for (int j = 0; j < pairsLetters.size(); ++j){

                if (pairsLetters.get(i).equals(pairsLetters.get(j))) continue;

                for (int k = 0; k < pairsLetters.size(); ++k){

                    if ((pairsLetters.get(i).equals(pairsLetters.get(k))) || (pairsLetters.get(j).equals(pairsLetters.get(k)))) continue;

                    words.add(pairsLetters.get(i) + pairsLetters.get(j) + pairsLetters.get(k));

                }
            }
        }

        return words;
    }
```

With this other method, I generate all possible combinations of numbers without repetition using two algorithms:

```
private void generateNumbersPairs(Values obj) {

        for (int i = 0; i < obj.getNumbers().size(); ++i){

            for (int j = 0; j < obj.getNumbers().size(); ++j){

                if (obj.getNumbers().get(i).equals(obj.getNumbers().get(j))) continue;

                    pairNumbers.add(obj.getNumbers().get(j)+obj.getNumbers().get(i));
                    pairNumbers.add(obj.getNumbers().get(i)+obj.getNumbers().get(j));

            }
        }

    }
```

That done, and used this method to generate all combinations of words with the value number at the end:

Generate words

```
private void getAllWords (List <String> words, List <String> pairNumbers) {
         for (int letter = 0; letter <6; ++ letter) {

             for (int number = 0; number <pairNumbers.size (); ++ number) {

                 if (words.equals (pairNumbers.get (number))) continue;

                 saveNewWord (words, pairNumbers, number);

             }
         }
     }
```

Save words

```
     private void saveNewWord (List <String> pairs, List <String> pairNumbers, int number) {
         String word = String.join ("", words);

         allWords.add (word + pairNumbers.get (number));
     }
```

My problem is that since the number of words is huge, when my method goes through 'for', it is not possible for me to complete such a calculation, because the method consumes more memory than I have.
Would there be some way to better this algorithm? Could someone help me with this?

Comment: You output array is 5^3*20^3*10*9*2 = 90000000 each string of 8 char take 16 bytes only to represent characters. It is 1.44GB. You have to add here arrays headers, objects headers and you easily can go to ~3GB. It means problem is not in your algorithm you need ~3GB to represent result.

Comment: But do you have any way to reduce consumption? would saving in a noSql database help, instead of saving in memory?

Comment: Why do you need to save them? Can't you just process them one at a time as you generate them? Creating an enormous dataset only to iterate over the entire dataset once is extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to store these "words".

You have 105 distinct syllables, and you can see the words as base-105 numbers. Depending on the processing you want to perform, you can encode the syllables on bytes (then for a complete enumeration you must carry every time a "digit" exceeds 104), or on integers (and provide a base conversion algorithm). In both cases, 32 bits integers can represent any word with up to four syllables.

But again, it is no use to store them explicitly. If you really have to, use a bit array. Representing the four syllable words will take about 15.2 MB.